# What is the complexity of bitwise operation of two sets?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, bitwise-operators

I was looking at the following line of code

`{1,5,3,4,2}&{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`
and was curious what the complexity of the bitwise operation & of two sets is in Python

I'd like to know how the bitwise operation on sets is performed under the hood.

Comment: `&` is the intersection of the two sets, the complexity is O(n) expected

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 5):

The `&` operator is just a shorthand for [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) it is not *"bitwise"* it is just another usage of `&`.

The time complexity is `O(min(n, m))` when `n` and `m` are the lengths of the two sets, respectively.

The source code written in `C` can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c#L1181).

Comment: Nice reference for the source +1.